# document.getElementById in a loop return null

Tags: javascript, php, loops, getelementbyid

I use Php and Javascript
My first page is appel.php

In which, I create a table with php in : constructAppel.inc.php
with datas from my database.

```
foreach ($rows as $row):
  $count = $count +1;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><button Onclick=ClickPresence('bt".$row['Id']."') id='bt".$row['Id']."' style='background-color:green;'>Oui</button></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Nom'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Prenom'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Cat'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><button onclick=window.location.href='vueparticipant.php?id=".$row['Id']."' id=". $row['Id'] ." class='material-icons'>assignment_ind</button></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
endforeach;
echo "</table>"
```

I want to change the background-color of my buttons with javascript (or maybe something else)

Php :

```
 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM dataappel WHERE Acti = '$ActiActu' AND Dat = '$Dat' AND Prof = '$Prof' AND Etab = '$Etab'");
  $stmt->execute();
  $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $count = $stmt->rowCount();
  if ($count > 0) {
    $list = '';
    foreach ($rows as $r) {
      $list .= "bt".$r['IdEleve'].",".$r['Appel']."/";
    }
```

My list is something like : bt55,Yes/bt45,No/bt21,Yes.

I want if value after comma = Yes then background of bt55 is green

Here my Script:

```
var list = '<?php echo $list; ?>'
    if (list != '') {
      ActuPresence(list);
    }

    function ActuPresence(list){
var list = '<?php echo $list; ?>'
  var a = list.split("/");

  for (var i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
    var b = a[i].split(",");
    var btn = b[0];
    console.log(document.getElementById(btn)) ;  

    if (b[1] = "No"){
      console.log(btn);
      btn.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      console.log("No");
    }
        if (b[1] = "Yes"){
      btn.style.backgroundColor =  "green";
      console.log("Yes");
    }
```

But document.getElementById(btn) return null.

Var a, var b and var btn return good value.
I know that bt55 exist because when i click on it, console.log return good id.

Comment: Did you verify the value of `btn` at that point? Do you actually have an element with an `id="..."` tag with those contents?

Comment: `<td><button onclick=window.location.href='vueparticipant.php?id=17' id=17 class='material-icons'>assignment_ind</button></td>` doesn't look like valid HTML for me - check your concatenations and quotes (and post the resulting HTML in your question aswell).

Comment: <button onclick=window.location.href='vueparticipant.php?id=17' id=17 class='material-icons'>assignment_ind</button> does what I want, no problem on this button.

Comment: btn return null at that point. I tried to put it somewhere else but nothing. I'm trying with window.onload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove onClick from the button and add class to it

```
echo "<td><button id='bt".$row['Id']."' style='background-color:green;' class='classname'>Oui</button></td>";
```

Then use window.onload

```
window.onload=function(){
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
className[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
    var list = '<?php echo $list; ?>'
    if (list != '') {
      ActuPresence(list);
    }
});
 function ActuPresence(list){
var list = '<?php echo $list; ?>'
var a = list.split("/");
for (var i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
var b = a[i].split(",");
var btn = b[0];
console.log(document.getElementById(btn)) ;  
if (b[1] = "No"){
  console.log(btn);
  btn.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  console.log("No");
 }
    if (b[1] = "Yes"){
  btn.style.backgroundColor =  "green";
  console.log("Yes");
 }
```

The problem in you code is that you call the ID before the page is ready so at the time of execution it is null

Comment: I get : Uncaught ReferenceError: className is not defined
    at window.onload. Did I put it somewhere wrong ?

Comment: OnClick=ClickPresence And function ActuPresence are not same things... ClickPresence change background color when I click on it and ActuPresence initialize color with informations from database

Comment: Can you explain me this : window.onload=function(){
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
className[0].addEventListener("click",function(){

Comment: The load event fires when a given resource has loaded Here after your page loaded the function have to be work and addEventListener is to add click event to your button , I guess that you have to try right click on the page and select view page source to check if everything about your classes and id is ok to check if your php return the exact page you want from the server

Comment: Sory you have to use classname with small n